# Add item to xamarin list view

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a list view like this:

[image]

how i can add some items to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use adapters to populate data into ListView.
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/part_2_-_populating_a_listview_with_data/

Not adding subviews directly to listview because of performance issues. When you connect adapter to listview them generate views only for visible rows and then recycle them.

Btw recyclerview https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/recyclerview/ is much more powerful and moder then listview.

Comment: your right pogonets,thank you :)

Comment: now i have a list name:list1.how i can use an adapter? codes in the link are not useful.please give me an adapter for a list with name:list1

Comment: It depends on data which you whant to populate inside listview and layout of single item. Basically data is stored in adapter and adapter know how to make view for each dataitem.

Comment: yep,it got fixed :)